# Guice scope and AssistedInject

Tags: java, guice, assisted-inject

I have code which uses AssistedInject to create factories of my classes. Now what I want to do is create a number of objects, each of which gets injected with a different item of a collection (reverse Multibinding one could say).

My approach is to use a custom Scope which contains the Iterator to provide the Items, but I am doing something wrong:

IterationScope.java:

```
public class IterationScope implements Scope {

  private Iterator<?> iterator;

  public IterationScope() {
  }

  /**
   * provide scoped Items
   * @param key - the key for the requested item
   * @param unscoped - the unscoped provider
   * @param <T> - the type of the requested object
   * @return - the requested provider
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public <T> Provider<T> scope(Key<T> key, Provider<T> unscoped) {
    return Providers.<T>of((T)iterator.next());
  }

  public void enterScope(Iterator<?> iterator) {
    this.iterator = iterator;
  }

}
```

IterationScoped.java:

```
@Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@ScopeAnnotation @BindingAnnotation
public @interface IterationScoped {
}
```

In the module:

```
IterationScope itScope = new IterationScope();
bindScope(IterationScoped.class, itScope);
bind(IterationScope.class).toInstance(itScope);
bind(ImplementationDataType.class).annotatedWith(IterationScoped.class).toProvider(Providers.of(null)).in(itScope);
/* do AssistedInject stuff */
```

I try to get the value like this:

```
@Inject @IterationScoped ImplementationDataTypedataType
```

And set the scope like this:

```
@Inject private IterationScope iterationScope; 

[...]
iterationScope.enterScope(someCollection.iterator);
for (ImplementationDataType message: someCollection){   
generatorChain.addNextFileGenerator(generatorFactory.create(param1,false));
}
```

The problem I have is that already when creating the factories, I get a NullPointerException in IteratorScope.scope because no Iterator is set.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.conti.xcit.utilities.guice.IterationScope.scope(IterationScope.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Scoping.scope(Scoping.java:240)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BindingProcessor$1.visit(BindingProcessor.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BindingProcessor$1.visit(BindingProcessor.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInstanceBindingImpl.acceptTargetVisitor(ProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BindingProcessor.visit(BindingProcessor.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BindingProcessor.visit(BindingProcessor.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BindingImpl.acceptVisitor(BindingImpl.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:177)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createChildInjector(InjectorImpl.java:217)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createChildInjector(InjectorImpl.java:224)
    at [... where I inject the Factory ... ]
```

My expectation would have been that the factory only tries to find the scoped provider when I actually request an object, not at creation of the factory. Is there any way to get around this? I have an ugly idea involving a scoped provider with an incrementing counter in order to select the right item of the collection, but I would like a cleaner approach.

Comment: What if you work with actual keys instead of relying on unreliable keys like undefined iterator items. I actually believe you're in an X Y situation where you try to solve something X by implementing Y and you face issue in Y, but X is your real problem. So would you please try to explain the business case you're trying to solve? This way we can probably help you with the actual need you have instead of trying to fix clunky links for which we require much, much more code.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire The business case is that I am too lazy to implement another Factory interface for the AssistedInject and instead use an approach that is more ugly, more work, and more error-prone. I think I may have to rethink and just create a second factory interface that includes the parameter that I am trying to inject with a scope here.

Comment: For the record, I did in the end just create a second factory interface.